# Чтение имен файлов с пробелами в bash

Tags: bash

Нужно написать скрипт поиска одинаковых по содержанию файлов в двух каталогах. В цикле for поочередно сравниваю файлы, но в качестве списка аргумента переменной беру список файлов в каталоге. Проблема в том, что если в имени файла есть пробелы, то переменная цикла читает имя файла только до пробела, а файл с таким именем собственно не существует. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.

```
 for file1 in `ls $1 | xargs -n 1 -i echo "$1/{}"`
  do
      for file2 in `ls $2 | xargs -n 1 -i echo "$2/{}"`
      do 
         {
          diff -acs "$file1" "$file2" > "/home/user/OC/rez" 
          if  [ $? ] 
          then
                  echo "ololo"
           fi
         }
       done
   done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зачем так? А чем хуже просто `for file in $1/*`? К тому же `if  [ $? ]` -- что-то непонятное, а если /home/user/OC/rez должны храниться все результаты, а не только последний, то его надо дописывать. Если он не нужен, то `diff -q ... >/dev/null`). Если в $1 и $2 нет подкаталогов (или их не надо сравнивать), то:

```
 rm /home/user/OC/rez
 for file1 in $1/*
    do for file2 in $2/*
        do if diff -asc $file1 $file2 >>/home/user/OC/rez
            then echo ololo
           fi
        done
    done
```

Далее. При таком подходе вы запущаете diff для каждой пары файлов. Сколько файлов, и какие они, я не знаю. Но в большинстве случаев лучше бы сравнивать не их, а их свёртки по md5 (например). Утилита md5sum. Если у файлов должны совпадать имена, то количество сравнений содержимого существенно уменьшается (тогда, вероятно, и с md5 нет смысла заморачиваться).

Answer (score 3):

А почему нельзя проще:

```
for file1 in "$1"/*
```